# How to call a Composable in a different module from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple app with an android library module. I am learning how to call a `composable` across modules in jetpack compose. How do you do it?
Here is the MainActivity from the app module:

```
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                        Greeting("Android")
                        secondScreen.Asnackbar()
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
            text = "Hello $name!",
            modifier = modifier
    )
}
```

and here is a composable from a file in another android library module:

```
import androidx.compose.material3.Snackbar
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable


    @Composable
    fun Asnackbar(){
        Snackbar {
            Text("this is a snackbar")
        }
    }
```

The project compiled fine but on launching on an emulator, it crashed right away with this error
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method Asnackbar(Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;I)V in class Lcom/example/second_screen/SecondScreen; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.example.second_screen.SecondScreen' appears in /data/data/com.example.myapplication/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dex)`

NOTE: I have found out the answer. It is here [For JetpackCompose, can we create our Composable Function in another library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68816470/for-jetpackcompose-can-we-create-our-composable-function-in-another-library)

So all I need to do is adding these lines to my secondscreen module:
buildFeatures {
compose true
}
composeOptions {
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.5.1'
}

Comment: I think you are taking about multi-module architecture. Right?

Comment: Yes. My question says so, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, You are right. you need to refer some example on GIthub. It might help you a lot. Refer this repo : https://github.com/mykola-kichatov/android-clean-template

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the composable directly without any object reference to it like you have call the composable on `secondScreen` object there is nothing like that. All you need to just `import` the composable and use it although when you use it android studio will automatically import it for you.

**Note:** Make sure that you have implemented the android library module in the app level `build.gradle` file and synced properly.

Comment: Yes. I did implement the secondscreen module. Now I call `Asnackbar` directly in MainActiviy. The project compiled but the app crashes with the error I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Correction in MainActivity

```
import *.*.*.Asyncbar

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                        Greeting("Android")
                        Asnackbar()
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The app still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

*Call to other screen in jetpack compose; Please add this dependency on build.gradle *

```
implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.2")
```

*then add Routes class*

```
sealed class Routes(val route: String) {
object Toolbar : Routes("Toolbar")
object Splash : Routes("Splash")
object Login : Routes("Login")
object Signup : Routes("Signup")
object ForgotPass : Routes("ForgotPass")}
```

*then create navigation file*

```
@Composable fun Navigation(){
val navController = rememberNavController()
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Routes.Splash.route) {
    composable(Routes.Splash.route) {
        SplashScreen(navController = navController)
    }
    composable(Routes.Login.route) {
        LoginScreen(navController = navController)
    }
    composable(Routes.Signup.route) {
        SignupScreen(navController = navController)
    }
    composable(Routes.Toolbar.route) {
        CustomToolbarScreen(navController = navController, title = String())
    }
    composable(Routes.ForgotPass.route) {
        ForgotPasswordScreen(navController = navController)
    }
}}
```

*then add code in MainActivity*

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        TaxyTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                //Greeting("Android")
                Navigation()
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    TaxyTheme {
        Navigation()
    }
}
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun SplashPreview() {
    TaxyTheme {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        SplashScreen(navController = navController )
    }
}}
```

*Then button clicked code one screen to another screen*

```
Button( onClick = { navController.navigate(Routes.Signup.route) }, colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Gray)) {
            Text(
                text = "SignUp",
                style = TextStyle(fontSize = 14.sp)
            )
        }
```

**I am also new for jetpack composed**
[just start with new project on github](https://github.com/Rahul9545/Taxy.git)